# Transfer data through wifi of the computer instead of bluetooth (like Xender for mobile)?

Tags: android, wifi, data-transfer

Is there any software that can transfer data through wifi of the computer instead of Bluetooth like Xender for mobile?

So as to achieve higher data tranfer speed across two computer or across computer and mobile (Android).

Comment: You'll need to provide way more information to make this a viable question. What mobile platform for example?

Answer (score 1):

- For PC to PC you can use [IPMSG](https://ipmsg.org/index.html.en).
- For PC to Android you can use [SHAREit](http://shareit.lenovo.com/). SHAREit is a free application that lets you share files and folders among smartphones, tablets, and personal computers.

Comment: Same note as on your other post, Kamal: Just dropping in some links without explanation doesn't do here. Please see [our answer-guidelines](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) for details. And please take care for proper links. Thanks!